# How the credit card number is stored in the database while using Activemerchant gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I am working on a maintenance project which is in Rails 3.2.3. Here for payments they are using Active Merchant gem for Paypal integration.
As per the code review I did, mostly the code is written based on this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant). In this cast there is views/orders/new.html.erb file, the same written in my application. The main thing I need to know is when I enter a credit card number, it is saved as "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1111". I couldn't find in the code, how it is replaced with xxxx and followed by last 4 digit? Does Active Merchant have any mechanism to encrypt this card number? Please help me.